# How to emit event in socket.io based on client?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am working on realtime data visualization application using `node.js, express and socket.io`.

#### Requirement:

Have to emit the events based on the client request.

**For example**: If user enter the url as `http://localhost:8080/pages` socket.io should emit the topic `pages` to client and another user request for `http://localhost:8080/locations` socket should emit `location` to that particular user.

#### Code

```
    var server = app.listen("8080");
    var socket = require('socket.io');
    var io = socket.listen(server);
    var config = {};
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
          config.socket = io.sockets.socket(socket.id);
          socket.on('disconnect', function () {
             console.log('socket.io is disconnected');
          });
    });



    app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
      var url = req.url;
      var eventName = url.substring('/'.length);
       //pages and locations
      config.socket.volatile.emit(eventName, result);
    });
```

Client Code:

```
          //No problem in client code.Its working correctly. 
            Sample code as follows
          socket.on('pages', function (result) {
               console.log(result);
          });
```

#### Problem:

It is emitting `pages` and `locations` to both the clients.

Any suggestion to overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you please make this clear that do you want to render a different page to client when he enters 'http://localhost:8080/pages' or 'http://localhost:8080/locations', Or you want to emit some kind of data based on different URL?

Comment: @MOmary I am rendering different page and at the same time have to emit data to the client. Emitting is working correctly. Problem is messed up with different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand your approach on this, but because you said you're rendering different pages, It means you can serve different code, so what about doing it like this:

**Server Side:**

```
var server = app.listen("8080");
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);
var config = {};

app.get('/pages', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages.html');
});

app.get('/locations', function(req, res) {
  res.render('locations.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('pagesEvent', function(data){
     socket.volatile.emit('pages', {your: 'data'});
   });
   socket.on('locationsEvent', function(data){
     socket.volatile.emit('locations', {your: 'data'});
   });
});
```

**On Client side:**

**pages.html:**

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('pagesEvent', {});
});
socket.on('pages', function(data){
  // do stuff here
});
```

**locations.html:**

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('locationsEvent', {});
});
socket.on('locations', function(data){
  // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: First of all thanks, I am doing the stuff similar to the above code. For example: client A request for 'pages' and client B request for 'locations'. In the network panel(client B) i am seeing the both the events. pages and locations instead it should only receive `locations` event result.

Comment: With this code, I don't think that locations.html will receive the pages event. Other possibility is that you could be firing your event with io.sockets.emit('pagesEvent'); Because this fires events to all connected clients

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong, WebSockets supposed to work same in both directions. Client emit event to Server, server emit back to Client/Subscribers.

The way you are doing things, seems like a way of implementing API, but for some reason you are trying to implement it with WebSockets, instead of XHR.